STM32H7 CortexM4 DMA problem
I do have a STM32H755ZIT6 as a UART receiver via DMA on the CortexM4 core and STM32F103CBT6 as UART transmitter.
Transmitter sends 8 bytes [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
I read this article DMA is not working on STM32H7 devices 
and added
RAM_D2 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
RAM_D3 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
and changed .data .bss and _user_heap_stack memories to RAM_D3
into my M4's flash.ld file and now it looks like this:
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x08100000, LENGTH = 1024K
  RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 288K
  RAM_D2 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 288K
  RAM_D3 (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x38000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

.data :
{
  . = ALIGN(4);
  _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
  *(.data)           /* .data sections */
  *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
  *(.RamFunc)        /* .RamFunc sections */
  *(.RamFunc*)       /* .RamFunc* sections */

  . = ALIGN(4);
  _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
} >RAM_D3 AT> FLASH  /*  /* > RAM AT> FLASH was before */


.bss :
{
  /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss section */
  _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
  __bss_start__ = _sbss;
  *(.bss)
  *(.bss*)
  *(COMMON)

  . = ALIGN(4);
  _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
  __bss_end__ = _ebss;
} >RAM_D3  /* > RAM was before */

._user_heap_stack :
{
  . = ALIGN(8);
  PROVIDE ( end = . );
  PROVIDE ( _end = . );
  . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
  . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
  . = ALIGN(8);
} >RAM_D3 /* > RAM was before */

This is my configuration:



and my code is the simplest:
//__attribute__((section(".RAM_D3"))) uint8_t pressure_dma[4];
__attribute__ ((aligned (32))) uint8_t* pressure_dma[8];

 ....
err = HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart3, pressure_dma, 8);

//__asm("DSB");
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart4, pressure_dma, 8, 1000);

Also disabled and enabled I cache and d cache but I'm not receiving a proper data.
this is an example of received data
00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 0f 00 00
Polling method works fine, but DMA is not working. What else can I do?

Are you 100% sure that you've disabled the D-Cache and it stays disabled? (i.e: nothing else re-enables it)... Have you tried calling SCB_CleanDCache() after the data is placed in the buffer to push the caches out to RAM?

@Attie it's M4 , I can not call SCB_CleanDCache() as I know. I disabled it from CubeMX and I don't have anything in my code that enables or even "touches" D cache at all

__attribute__ ((aligned (32))) uint8_t* pressure_dma[8]; - what * is doing there? Looks like you aren't using it as array of pointers.
